# Cartoon about a couple that form a shade and then a robot

Tags: story-identification, robots, cartoon

I watched this cartoon as a kid; it is about an anime. It's about one couple that together they look into each other and form like a shade, and then it goes into a robot or form a robot.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: It's a cartoon *about* an anime?

Comment: You may want to add more details, such as when you watched it, what language it was in, other details from the story and so on. Good luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "like a shade"? Like a lamp shade?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds vaguely like [*Symbionic Titan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sym-Bionic_Titan).

> Billed as "an exciting hybrid of high school drama and giant robot battles", Sym-Bionic Titan features "the adventures of three beings from the planet Galaluna who crash-land on Earth while attempting to escape their war-torn world". The series follows the lives of Lance (voiced by Kevin Thoms), Ilana (Tara Strong) and Octus (Brian Posehn), two alien teens and a robot in the form of humanoids who arrive on Earth, an "identical" planet to Galaluna, while fleeing an evil general who has taken over their home planet with the help of monstrous creatures called Mutraddi.
>
> The three main characters include Ilana, princess of the royal family; Lance, a rebellious but capable soldier; and Octus, a bio-cybernetic robot, all of whom must now blend into everyday life in Sherman, Illinois. Posing as high school students, Lance and Octus work to conceal Princess Ilana from General Modula (Don Leslie) and his hideous space mutants sent to kill the sole heir of Galaluna.
>
> When called into battle, the Galalunans are outfitted with individual armor that provides more than ample protection. It is when the gravest of danger appears that Octus activates the sym-bionic defense program and he, Ilana, and Lance unite "Heart, Body and Mind" and come together to form the spectacular cyber-giant Sym-Bionic Titan.